# Reading Excel data with its exact data format using xlrd in Python

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

I am trying to read Excel file using xlrd, A cell in an Excel file is like 50.00%. When I was trying to read this cell, it returns float:0.5 
I know the Excel stores it as a numeric value, but I want it in a exact data format. 
Is there any way to get the value as it is from the excel?

```
for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
    for colnum in xrange(worksheet.ncols):
        # when reading the cell having data 50.00%
        cell = worksheet.cell(rownum,colnum)            # returns cell: number:0.5
        cell_type = worksheet.cell_type(rownum, colnum) # cell_type:2
        cell_value = cell.value                         # cell_value:0.5
```

**Data from Excel:**

```
Field1  Field2  FieldN  ...
data1   23234   50.00%
data2   23235   0.06%
```

**Data returned from xlrd:**

```
Field1  Field2  FieldN  ...
data1   23234   0.5     
data2   23235   0.000555
```

I need exact data format 0.06% instead of 0.000555

Comment: In my Excel file, there are n number of columns with number values. In this case I cant predict which field is having data like this.

Comment: How do you know what is displayed in cell? If I change display precision to 1 digit more in Excel, the actual value is still  `0.000555`, but now it displays `0.56%` instead of `0.6%`. There is no way Python can know what display precision is inside the cell. It's up to you to decide how you will round it, and if you need to append "%" sign to it. Moreover, every calculation is done with the actual value, not the displayed one. So I don't even understand why you would ever need that?

Comment: @dgan - The display precision is actually a formatting attribute stored in the file, so in principle it can be read. xlrd happens to not include code to read this in .xlsx files (it can read some formatting information in .xls files). I don't use OpenPyXL myself, but maybe it reads the numeric format string.